# Possible for a row of inline images to not trigger horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css

Does anyone know if it is possible to display a group of inline images horizontally in a row (or any element at that), allowing the group to extend beyond the right edge of the screen, without triggering the horizontal scrollbar?

A quick example:

```
<div class="page_container" style="width:900px; position:relative">
  <div class="image_set">    
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    ...etc
  </div>
</div>
```

The catch is that the image_set div that I would like to extend to, or beyond the right edge of the browser, is contained in a 900px div. The image_set needs to extend outside of its container, and to, or past the edge of the browser window.. without triggering a scrollbar.

The 900px wide page_container element needs to interact normally with the browser window (triggering scrollbars), and the element must contain the images. However, the images must be allowed to flow off the right edge of the browser window (visually)

So I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this with css only, without javascript?

Answer (score 4):

Just make the container div have a fixed width and then give it the `overflow: hidden` proprty. So something like:

```
<div class="image_set" style="width:100%; overflow: hidden;">    
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
    <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="400" />
</div>
```

By default `overflow` is `auto` which will apply scroll bars when needed thus setting it to `hidden` will mean that anything which does break the container will just disappear without needing scrollbars, and since for you that is the edge of the window, the effect will be complete.

---

In order to have the containing div cover the width of the entire page, you must first alter its layout model from `block` (which determines its width via its parent div) to `absolute` or `fixed`.

With the property `position: absolute` a div is positioned relative to its first parent with a `relative` position, this is usually the window itself, thus you can make the container div for the filmstrip use this property:

```
<div class="image_set" style="position: absolute; width:100%; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the image_set to extend to the right edge of the browser window, rather than just the right edge of the page_container. For example, if the page is 1100px...

Comment: OK I will modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Marcus by default `overflow` is `auto`

Comment: @Marcus The page_container element is unfortunately relatively positioned, so absolutely positioning the image_set div doesn't help.

Comment: It is the image_set div which should be absolutely positioned. The one which directly wraps the in-line image.s

Comment: @Marcus ya sorry, misread. My page_container element is already relatively positioned, so absolutely positioning the image_set doesn't help. I should mention that this is just an example. In my actual case, the page_container div is already nested deep in an html structure.

Comment: Do you have the freedom to move the `image_set` div outside (to just below) the `page_container` div? because that would solve it.

Comment: @Marcus Ya, my thoughts as well. I could move the entire image_set with jquery, but hoping not to. Just hoping that there was some whitespace, or overflow trick that I haven't considered before I start pulling things apart. In my example, it sounds like a simple refactor, but in my actual case, involves unravelling and refactoring some css, js widgets, etc.

Comment: Right well if you are using jQuery you could probably position the `image_set` div absolutely as before, but then set the size with jQuery to be the width of the page, and then update that width on a window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want to prevent is a double scroll bar?

try:

```
<div class="image_set" style="width:100%;position: relative;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply as well. I need the images to extend to, or beyond the right edge of the browser window, rather then the page_container. It's an odd situation. Basically I need to create a single div which could have unlimited width, and be completely ignored by the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/Vppxp/

**CSS**

```
#filmstrip {
    border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(220,220,220);
    border-top: solid 5px rgb(220,220,220);
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#filmstrip .cell {
    background: rgb(220,220,220);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#filmstrip .cell + .cell {
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="filmstrip">
    <div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very cool app (jsfiddle). This is generally how I'm setting up my elements as well, but this solution doesn't take into account the page_container divy. I need your #filmstrip element to extend beyond it's container div, and extend to, or off, the right edge of the browser window.